# Detecting a cancelled itunes login alert for in-app purchases

Tags: ios, objective-c, storekit

I have a class that implements `SKPaymentTransactionObserver`. However when clicking a buy button, if the user is not signed into the app store they get an alert asking for an existing ID or to create a new one. If the use clicks cancel from this, or a subsequent login credentials alert, I receive no notification of that cancellation. I have an activity view covering the screen after the buy button is clicked so I really need to know if the login alert was cancelled.

I already test for the error code `SKErrorPaymentCancelled` and that works if the purchase process is cancelled after logging in. I'm testing on a device.

Any clues?

-UPDATE-

Apologies I forgot to mention that this only happened when attempting to restore transactions, and that reveals the answer: my lack of knowledge about the protocol.

Comment: Kind of a hack but you can listen for the UIApplicationWillResignActive notification, which should get called when the alert view appears.

Answer (score 37):

To detect the cancel event after a user tries to cancel a restore purchases request implement:

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    // test error.code, if it equals SKErrorPaymentCancelled it's been cancelled
}
```

Comment: This helped me with the same issue - I was beating my head against the wall for hours and couldn't get a decent search response - THANKS!

Answer (score 10):

In Swift 3.0

```
public func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError error: Error) {
        print("Cancel Transaction");
    }
```

Comment: Not sure why the down vote...correct answer is above, followed by the correct answer translated to Swift 2.2, and this one gets it to Swift 3.0

Answer (score 2):

In Swift 2.2

```
public func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue, restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError error: NSError) {
    print("Cancel Transaction")

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When a user cancels the prompt that has them enter their Apple ID credentials, the state of the transaction is `SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed`. This can be confusing because the transaction hasn't technically "failed" if the user exited out of the process willingly. To detect if the user has actually exited out of the process, check if the error code of the transaction error (accessed by `transaction.error.code`) is `SKErrorPaymentCancelled`. If it isn't, the app actually had issues processing the transaction.