# How to know the exact time of appearing of itunes login alert during in app purchase restoring?

Tags: iphone, xcode, in-app-purchase, restore

I am restoring in app purchases in my application. An alert window for iTunes login will be shown(If I am not already logged in) after few seconds when I click restore button. I want to know when this alert is shown exactly because I want to show an actvity indicator during this few seconds. Is there any methods such as using Notifications for doing this?

I'm restoring the purchases using the below code

```
-(IBAction)inAppRestoreButAxn:(id)sender
 {
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
 }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No This is storekit function and we cant get the time interval here.

Comment: @MonishBansal   Is there a way to know if the user clicks the 'cancel' button of the alert?

Comment: No I dont think so. i also implemented in app yesterday and tried to find out cancel event. But didn't got cancel event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer for this in an another post in StackOverflow.

[Detecting a cancelled itunes login alert for in-app purchases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14711148/detecting-a-cancelled-itunes-login-alert-for-in-app-purchases)